# jquery hover effect not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

You can see my codes on Jsfiddle. When you hover a text you can see a small image from bottom to up with slide effect. But its working on last image only. I want to do the samething for all links with specific images for particular text.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8UNNz/2/)

**Jquery**

```
$('.one').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find('.inside').animate({
                bottom: '0%'
            }, 'fast' );
        },function() {
            $(this).find('.inside').animate({
                bottom: '-100%'
            },'fast');
        }
    );
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">
    <br />
    <a href="#">First image</a>
    <div class="inside"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1afb384456d02c2deee372f232b9bd9c?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="60" height="60" /></div>
    <br />
    <a href="#">Second image</a>
    <div class="inside"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8c3e29cdce11af820abb42524b47c424?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG" width="60" height="60" /></div>
    <br />
    <a href="#">Third image</a>
    <div class="inside"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d3c9b47a12b3dd664520e5d9dd22d741?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="60" height="60" /></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one
{
    overflow: hidden;
            position: absolute;
}

.one .inside
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100%;
}

a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: What is it you want to do? all the `.inside` is animating. its when you hover the `.one` it will animate all the `.inside` elements. is it when you hover the a-element you want to animate the sibling `.inside`?

Comment: @voigtan : i'm trying to do this following thing -> if you hover a first image text that first image should animate, then if you hover a second image text that second image should animate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the markup you could go with:

**edit:**

```
<div class="one">
    <br />
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1afb384456d02c2deee372f232b9bd9c?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG" class="inside" />
        First image
    </a>

    <br />
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8c3e29cdce11af820abb42524b47c424?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG" class="inside" />
        Second image
    </a>

    <br />
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d3c9b47a12b3dd664520e5d9dd22d741?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"class="inside"/>
        Third image
    </a>

</div>
```

and change the css and javascript code:

```
.one a
{
    position: relative;
}

.one .inside
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}

a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('.one a, .one .inside').hover(
    function(e) {
        var el = $(this).find('.inside');
       var isHover = e.type === 'mouseenter';
        el.stop(true).animate({
            top: isHover ? '0%' : '100%',
            opacity: isHover ? 1 : 0
        }, 'fast' );
    }
);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8UNNz/12

Comment: this is what i want. but, images not fully shown and then effect will animate when i hover the cursor outside of div..

Comment: you will need to change the markup (what I can see) to make this to work. I have updated the fiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/8UNNz/6/

Comment: are you sure? have you looked on the jsfiddle example I linked? does seem to work on Firefox and chrome (the only browers I tested your code with)

Comment: yes i'm sure. i've seen the jsfiddle code. but all images comes from the last text bottom. i want the particular image should come from the particular text bottom..

Comment: Sorry mate, I will give up, I first did that each image came under the specific text row, and thats not what you wanted and now that it displays the correct image with the animation it's not what you wanted either. either you need to change the z-index on the image and skip the overflow hidden.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45982/discussion-between-voigtan-and-user3181207)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to nest the link and div. I forked your fiddle to something that works: http://jsfiddle.net/2SRf2/

HTML

```
<div class="one">
<br />
<div>
    <a href="#">First image</a>
    <div class="inside"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1afb384456d02c2deee372f232b9bd9c?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="60" height="60" /></div>
    <br />
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#">Second image</a>
    <div class="inside"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8c3e29cdce11af820abb42524b47c424?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG" width="60" height="60" /></div>
    <br />
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#">Third image</a>
    <div class="inside"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d3c9b47a12b3dd664520e5d9dd22d741?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="60" height="60" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('a').hover(
function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.inside').animate({
            bottom: '0%'
        }, 'fast' );
    },function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.inside').animate({
            bottom: '-100%'
        },'fast')
}
```

);

Comment: its working. but when i hover a first text that particular image should come from the first text bottom. but images always come from the last text bottom..